# How to add a dummy column with different values to the result of a select query?

Tags: sql, select, google-bigquery

I have a table containing a column `Bucket`, I want to add one more column with some random time stamp values for each Bucket in the select query so as to get a table like below one. How can I achieve this ?

| Bucket | created_on |
| --- | --- |
| bucket-1 | 2000-06-02 00:37:12 |
| bucket-2 | 2005-06-02 23:50:19 |
| bucket-5 | 2020-06-02 12:21:12 |
| bucket-3 | 2019-06-02 20:28:19 |

Comment: is there any logic for those random timestamps? like within the specific range for example? or how they should be distributed? etc.

Comment: They're completely random.

Comment: Hello @xvzf. Do the existing answers satisfy your requirement? If they don't, can you please explain why?

Comment: I got some idea after looking the below approaches, though none of them was exact solution to my problem but I was able to get the query working using the below answers as pointers.

Answer (score -1):

You can calculate a unixtime between two dates and transform it into a date, adding a randon number makes it random

```
#standardSQL
WITH parameters AS (
  SELECT  DATE '2010-01-01' start_date, DATE '2022-04-08' finish_date
)
SELECT t1.Bucket, DATE_FROM_UNIX_DATE(CAST(start_date + (finish_date - start_date) * RAND() AS INT64)) random_date
FROM table1 t1  CROSS JOIN parameters p
```